# Book recommendations for learning financial/business mathematics.

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, finance

Does anyone know a book which covers topics on:

> Simple interest
>
> Compound interest
>
> Equations of equivalent values
>
> Nominal rate, effective rate and equivalent rate
>
> Annuities
>
> Amortization
>
> General accounting
>
> Bookkeeping
>
> Inflation calculations

I would like something in-depth, but at an introductory level.

Note: It must be a book that is **not** in Spanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend "Theory of Interest" by Stephen Kellison.

As an additional reference, you could also check out "Mathematics of Investment" by William Hart.

Comment: Does this book include general accounting?

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers: Yes, as far as I could recall, I do think that Kellison's book touches on general accounting principles.